# get today's date with parsed time in moment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am trying to get the today's date with the time which I specified using moment js. My attempt is as below.

```
const time = '18:00'
const timeAndDate = moment(time)
```

But when I print `timeAndDate` it says invalid date. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: the documentation would suggest `moment(time, 'HH:mm')` is what you want - i skimmed through it after reading the question ... so ... yeah

Comment: If you are not using a custom format, here is what you can use: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ `'HH:mm'` is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
const minute = 0
const hour = 18
const timeAndDate = moment().hours(hour).minutes(minute);
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to specify the time format like second parameter in moment

```js
const timeOfToday = moment('18:00', 'HH:mm');
console.log(timeOfToday);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```